# Помогите определить характер речевых ошибок, допущенных абитуриентом

Tags: грамотная-речь, коммуникативные-требования

В сочинении  "Тема падения и духовного возрождения человека в произведениях Ф. М. Достоевского (по роману "Преступление и наказание")" абитуриент употребил такую фразу:

"Раскольников пошел на дело, но сестра его не сдала".

В чем именно заключаются речевые ошибки, допущенные абитуриентом?

Какие коммуникативные требования нарушены?

Comment: К речевым ошибкам относятся не только лексико-семантические, но и стилистические, и грамматические ошибки (не путать с орфографическими). С семантикой (фактическая точность) тоже следует здесь более внимательно разобраться.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте описание для метки «коммуникативные-требования», иначе не понятно, зачем она нужна.

Comment: Я добавил описание метки, которое поставлено в очередь для экспертного рассмотрения..

Answer (score 5):

Речевых ошибок нет, просто автор сочинения высказался на уголовном жаргоне ("дело" вместо "преступление", "сдала" вместо "выдала"), будто сочинение это адресовано сокамернику или начальнику тюрьмы его подопечным, а не экзаменационной комиссии абитуриентом.

Comment: Но ведь это и есть стилистическая ошибка - просторечная, жаргонная лексика в школьном сочинении - в письменной речи.

Comment: Говоря об ошибках, я оцениваю текст сам по себе - возможны ситуации, к которым он бы подошёл по стилю.

Answer (score 3):

Что такое коммуникативные требования к речи? https://studopedia.ru/17_144298_kommunikativnie-kachestva-rechi--priznaki-horoshey-kulturnoy-rechi-kotorie-obespechivayut-effektivnost-obshcheniya-i-garmonichnoe-vzaimodeystvie-ego-uchastnikov.html

"Коммуникативные качества речи – признаки хорошей, культурной речи, которые обеспечивают эффективность общения и гармоничное взаимодействие его участников".

Другими словами, коммуникативность речи - это качественная и точная передача информации от одного лица к другому, что невозможно сделать без соблюдения  правил речевого общения.

Если говорить конкретно, то это (1) **правильность** (соблюдение языковых норм), (2) **точность** (смысловая), (3) **чистота** (отсутствие жаргонизмов, диалектизмов, бранной лексики, слов-паразитов).

Явно нарушен пункт 3 и сомнителен пункт 2 (предложение не соответствует реальным событиям романа, сестра ничего не знала о намерениях героя).